# Mean time to failure calculation help

Tags: computer-architecture

Given this formula how do you calculate the following? I don't understand, can some one explain?

```
                      1
MTTF(System) = ------------------------
           [Summation]      1
                       ------------
                          MTTFi
```

(was going to upload an image of the formula but "they" don't let me)

- A 10 TB disk drive has an MTTF of 6,000,000 hours.  How much data can we store in a system comprised of these disks, if we want the system MTTF to be at least 1.2M hours?
- If we are allowed to make it redundant (i.e., two of them operating in a parallel mode), and if the MTTR is 120 hours, what is the system MTTF?